# trying to deploy to DO with capistrano. got an error when cap deploy:cold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean

> - executing "cd --
>     /home/harris/harrisrobin.co/releases/20140128225905 &&
>     RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake
>     assets:precompile"
>     servers: ["198.199.122.209"]
>     [198.199.122.209] executing command  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209] rake aborted!  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out ::
>     198.199.122.209] Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available
>     runtimes.  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]
>     /home/harris/harrisrobin.co/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in
>     `autodetect'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out ::
>     198.199.122.209] /home/harris/harrisrobin.co/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in`
>     '  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out ::
>     198.199.122.209] /home/harris/harrisrobin.co/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in
>     `<top (required)>'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out ::
>     198.199.122.209] /home/harris/harrisrobin.co/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.4.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in`
>     require'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]
>     /home/harris/harrisrobin.co/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.4.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in
>     `<top (required)>'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out ::
>     198.199.122.209] /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in`
>     require'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]
>     /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in
>     `block (2 levels) in require'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out
>     :: 198.199.122.209]
>     /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`
>     each'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]
>     /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in
>     `block in require'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out ::
>     198.199.122.209] /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in`
>     each'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]
>     /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in
>     `require'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]
>     /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in`
>     require'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]
>     /home/harris/harrisrobin.co/releases/20140128225905/config/application.rb:7:in
>     `<top (required)>'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out ::
>     198.199.122.209] /home/harris/harrisrobin.co/releases/20140128225905/Rakefile:4:in`
>     require'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]
>     /home/harris/harrisrobin.co/releases/20140128225905/Rakefile:4:in
>     `'  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209]   ** [out ::
>     198.199.122.209] (See full trace by running task with --trace)  ** [out :: 198.199.122.209] 
>     command finished in 2183ms
>     *** [deploy:update_code] rolling back   * executing "rm -rf /home/harris/harrisrobin.co/releases/20140128225905; true"
>     servers: ["198.199.122.209"]
>     [198.199.122.209] executing command
>     command finished in 354ms failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'cd --
>     /home/harris/harrisrobin.co/releases/20140128225905 &&
>     RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake
>     assets:precompile'" on 198.199.122.209

Any ideas ? I have no clue what this means :

> command finished in 354ms failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm
>   $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'cd --

I am following this guide and got stuck at cap deploy:cold :
https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059332/could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime-see-https-github-com-sstephenson-execjs-f

Comment: Hi! are you sure you've linked me to the correct question ? Unless I'm missing something, I don't see how that question can help me at all.

Cheers and thanks,

Comment: Your error appears to be `Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes` and not the section you highlighted.  That question addresses the javascript runtime error.

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions in there, but nothing has worked for me. Thank you for the link though. I'll keep looking!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing JavaScript runtime library. Install NodeJS on the server using this:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Also, for rails deployments on DO and Ubuntu in general, this is a great resource for all the steps (and a video walkthrough):
https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04